# How to protect ado.net entity generated database on a local machine

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework

I have a C# application in .net 3.5 using SQL Server 2008 R2.

I am using ado.net Entity Framework to generate the database but after generating it when I remove the database file from SQL Server the framework does not generate the database.

I want to generate database on users local machine while installation and have a password on database access and protect the data from being read or modified by a local user rather than my application.

So the question is how to achieve this with out encrypting the whole data?

What is the parallels here?

Comment: "parallels"? - you send a person locked box with key and now trying to block the person from opening the box by listening to birds. (I guess good enough parallel to trying to give more permissions to code running under user's account than user has).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think EF in .NET 3.5 was ever capable of creating a database at runtime.

You'll have to either upgrade to .NET 4 and EF 5 or 6 to use **code-first** with **migrations** to handle this, or then you need to write some code to handle that situation yourself, in .NET 3.5.

Also: a SQL Server database (file) doesn't have a *password mechanism* like Access or other file-based system do. Access to a SQL Server database is handled **by the SQL Server itself** by means of logins on the server, users on the database-level and permissions for those users.